# React Router causing screen to go blank

Tags: reactjs, routes

first time asking for help here but i'm stumped. My react site renders correctly until i attempt to use Browser Router. as soon as i implement BrouwserRouter tag the the site no longer renders and all i get is a completely blank screen. Can anyone explain what i'm doing wrong here?

...

```
    import { NavBar, Download, Features, SectionWrapper } from "../src/components";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import assets from "./assets";
import "./index.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
     <BrowserRouter basename="/React">
       <NavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <SectionWrapper
              title="Lift Big"
              description="iNFO"
             showBtn
              mockupImg={assets.group1}
              banner="banner"
            />
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

...

...

```
   import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../src/App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
   <BrowserRouter>
     <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

...

...

```
"name": "LiftBig",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://liftbig.co.uk/relativepath",
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "heroicons-react": "^1.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

....

Section Wrapper

```
import React from "react";

import { styles } from "../styles/Global";

import { Button } from "../buttons/Button";

const SectionWrapper = ({
  title,
  description,
  showBtn,
  mockupImg,
  banner,
  reverse,
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`min-h-screen sticky ${styles.section} ${
        reverse ? styles.bgWhite : styles.bgPrimary
      } ${banner}`}
    >
      <div
        className={`flex items-center ${
          reverse ? styles.boxReverseClass : styles.boxClass
        } w-11/12 sm:w-full minmd:w-3/4`}
      >
        <div
          className={`${styles.descDiv} ${
            reverse ? "fadeRightMini" : "fadeLeftMini"
          }
          ${reverse ? styles.textRight : styles.textLeft}
          `}
        >
          <h1
            className={`
          ${reverse ? styles.blackText : styles.whiteText}
          
          ${styles.h1Text}`}
          >
            {title}
          </h1>
          <p
            className={` ${reverse ? styles.blackText : styles.whiteText} ${
              styles.descriptionText
            }`}
          >
            {description}
          </p>
          <div>
            <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <div>
                {showBtn && (
                  <Button
                    assetUrl={"google"}
                    link="Android Store"
                    info="App Store"
                  />
                )}
              </div>
              <div style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
                {showBtn && (
                  <Button
                    assetUrl={"apple"}
                    link="Android Store"
                    info="Play Store"
                  />
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={`flex-1 ${styles.flexCenter} p-8 sm:px-0`}>
          <img
            src={mockupImg}
            alt="mockup"
            className={`${styles.sectionImg} ${
              reverse ? "fadeleftMini" : "fadeRightMini"
            }`}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SectionWrapper;
```

Comment: you called BrowserRoute twice at App and Index.

Comment: Removed the call in the index.js file but the issues the same. Cheers though.

Comment: Can you show `SectionWrapper`?

Comment: I've just added Section Wrapper.

Comment: Look in your browser console, do you see any error message? If so paste it as well please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you might have to configure your webserver in order to make it work with BrowserRouter.

Let's say you (your browser) requests `/user` or `/user/profile`, the server needs to respond to this request with your application `index.html` file. Then on the client your app is started, the React Router kicks in and renderes the requested component. After that first request from your browser all further navigation is handled by React Router, so no server requests are anymore. But for the initial request your server must be able to return the `index.html`-page.

That is different from HashRouter, because with HashRouter, the part of the URL after the hash sign is never sent to your server, so the request that the server gets is normally only `/` (which is mapped to `index.html` anyway) and all navigation only takes place at client side.

A look in the console or network tab of your browser might get you more informations (for example HTTP 404 results for your requests if your server is not configured correctly).

Comment: Thanks NIls for the explanation, i've managed to get it working. Thanks for taking the time to point me in the right direction. I really appreciate it. I'd love to upvote your answer but apparently i need to work on my reputation first.